# A beginner facing difficulty using Google maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm Japanese and have been studying how to develop Android apps.

I conducted a research as thoroughly as possible, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'd appreciate any help.

I've been trying to show Google Map on Android. I tested it on my own Android device, version 4.1.2, but the map doesn't show. There are plus and minus button on the lower right corner, and a Google logo on the lower left.

I created a Google Maps Activity when I made the project on Android Studio. I checked "Phone and Tablet" and chose "API 14: Android 4.0."

The Only thing I did was to add my API key to the designated place in google_maps_api.xml.

---

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key_instructions" templateMergeStrategy="replace"><!--

    TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

    To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=68:29:3F:71:20:84:3B:89:B8:1D:C7:DC:92:27:CB:4E:BB:5E:54:25%3Bjp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter

    You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using this line:
    68:29:3F:71:20:84:3B:89:B8:1D:C7:DC:92:27:CB:4E:BB:5E:54:25;jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter

    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    --></string>

    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">AIzaSyCcHGPWSbnLqED8giZOe1WR2wkDJVaBup4</string>
</resources>
```

---

I've had the following APIs on.

Google Maps Android API v2, 
Google Maps Engine API, 
Google Maps Coordinate API, 
Google Maps Geolocation API, 
Google Play Android Developer API

---

I can't upload images because of the lack of reputations. So I'll type in what my Credentials page says.

Key for Android applications

API KEY AIzaSyCcHGPWSbnLqED8giZOe1WR2wkDJVaBup4

ANDROID APPLICATIONS 68:29:3F:71:20:84:3B:89:B8:1D:C7:DC:92:27:CB:4E:BB:5E:54:25;jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk

ACTIVATION DATE Aug 14, 2014 6:11 AM

ACTIVATED BY My Email (you)

---

And here's what it shows. Bold lines are colored in red, italic blue.

**08-25 20:31:13.618    5329-5335/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe**

**08-25 20:31:13.738    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)**

08-25 20:31:13.738    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25

08-25 20:31:13.738    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608

08-25 20:31:13.738    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152

08-25 20:31:13.968    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 4242000

*08-25 20:31:13.968    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 24934: Lgui;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgrh;*

**08-25 20:31:13.968    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a**

*08-25 20:31:13.968    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;*

**08-25 20:31:13.968    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a**

*08-25 20:31:13.968    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;*

**08-25 20:31:13.968    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a**

*08-25 20:31:13.968    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;*

08-25 20:31:13.978    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 5089036

*08-25 20:31:13.988    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;*

*08-25 20:31:13.988    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;*

*08-25 20:31:14.149    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed*

**08-25 20:31:14.149    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a**

*08-25 20:31:14.149    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lgls;*

08-25 20:31:14.269    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3097893)
    Build Date: 01/28/13 Mon
    Local Branch: AU139
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:

08-25 20:31:14.299    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter I/Adreno200-C2D﹕ : C2D2 initializing a3xx version: libc2d2_a3xx.so

08-25 20:31:14.299    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter I/Adreno200-C2D﹕ : C2D2 wrapper initialized successfully

08-25 20:31:14.299    5329-5329/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter I/Adreno200-C2D﹕ : Allocate CMD Buffer Address  0x5ca68000 0x1009a000

*08-25 20:31:15.510    5329-5408/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter W/ActivityThread﹕ ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());*

**08-25 20:31:16.241    5329-5408/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.**

08-25 20:31:32.098    5329-5408/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

08-25 20:32:18.607    5329-5331/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 6485K, 37% free 12633K/19907K, paused 27ms+5ms, total 166ms

08-25 20:57:06.917    5329-5331/jp.gr.java_conf.jbnrsk.walkmeter D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 3490K, 37% free 12649K/19907K, paused 16ms+9ms, total 133ms

---

Did I do something wrong in the process of making my fingerprint?

Although it includes Japanese, here's what I got when I created my fingerprint.

別名: androiddebugkey

作成日: 2014/07/03

エントリ・タイプ: PrivateKeyEntry

証明書チェーンの長さ: 1

証明書[1]:

所有者: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US

発行者: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US

シリアル番号: 53b55dbf

有効期間の開始日: Thu Jul 03 22:42:23 JST 2014終了日: Sat Jun 25 22:42:23 JST 2044

証明書のフィンガプリント:

```
 MD5:  79:2F:BC:C2:B0:F9:68:7D:02:DC:B3:3C:DF:61:94:C6

 SHA1: 68:29:3F:71:20:84:3B:89:B8:1D:C7:DC:92:27:CB:4E:BB:5E:54:25

 SHA256: 35:AA:49:D9:A3:A0:C4:AB:C8:E6:4D:30:2F:8C:40:A8:15:6C:04:0A:85:2C:76:FB:87:56:15:7A:9A:69:C1:64

 署名アルゴリズム名: SHA1withRSA

 バージョン: 3
```

---

I know I'm a beginner. It's very likely I've made a stupid mistake.

I'd appreciate it if you would give me any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this link??

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or an emulator? Is the network enabled?

Comment: I use a real device with Internet connection, which is my personal phone.

Answer (score 1):

As some have already mentioned, most likely you are unable to see the map because your application lacks permission to use network connectivity. You can fix it by modifying the AndroidManifest.xml located in your project root folder.

You should add line "uses-permission" before the "application" tag like shown below and specify the requested permission's name (android.permission.INTERNET in your case).

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
   ...
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
   <application
       ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```